# Java public / protected variable values inside inherited subclass is Null

Tags: java

I want to access a variable declared protected in Superclass, from  subclass.

The values are displayed `null` in subclass, though it displays correctly in superclass. If the superclass variable is static, it works, but the loop values are not taken correctly.

My code:

```
public class App {
    public String var ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        App ap = new App();
        ap.fromt();
    }

    public void fromt() {
        Sub s = new Sub();
        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            var = "Test" + i;
            System.out.println("Hello World!" + var);
            s.testtt();
        }
    }
}

//**Inherited Class**//
public class Sub extends App {
    public void testtt() {
        String var2 = super.var;
        System.out.println("Hello World! Subclass" + var2);
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Hello World!Test0
Hello World! Subclassnull
Hello World!Test1
Hello World! Subclassnull
Hello World!Test2
Hello World! Subclassnull
Hello World!Test3
Hello World! Subclassnull
Hello World!Test4
Hello World! Subclassnull
Hello World!Test5
Hello World! Subclassnull
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in java...but you have to use `this` keyword to make it work. something like `this.var = "Test"+i;` instead of `var = "Test"+i;`

Comment: You are not setting the `var` to anything before calling `s.testtt()`. Probably you wanted to do, `s.var = "Test"+i;`

Comment: Because in your App class, you have not defined var. When you call your Sub constructor, it will take that non-defined variable. In static case, since all objects declared share the same static variables, once you define the variable later, all other objects constructed from this class could use that variable

Comment: I can't see any `protected` variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're dealing with a matter of scope here.  You have the instance of App that is running, and within that instance you are running your loop and setting the value of your variable within this specific instance.  Then you are creating an instance of Sub that is currently maintaining its own instance of var within itself.

Now, if you want a singular instance of var shared across all instances of App/Sub then you would make it:

```
public static String var ;
```

I am assuming that this is for a homework assignment so I won't go into the pros and cons of this, but just know that static vars are one of those things you really have to think about for any sort of app.

Comment: Thank you Michael , I was doing a unit testing(the code here) to achieve the for loop values (from excel sheet) in my actual project.Unfortunately , I will not be able to use the public static String , Is there any other way I could get the values correctly?

Comment: As mentioned before just adding a constructor to your class would allow you to pass the value.  Or you could add a setter/getter.  Not sure why you are extending App to save a variable declaration though.

Answer (score 1):

The classes `Sub` and `App` do get their own the copies of the member variable `var` defined in the superclass.
**They are 2 different copies.**
Any changes made to one of the copies will remain mutually exclusive to the other. The things change when static members are used. Sharing of member data in inheritance should not be confused while the classes are instantiated.

To answer your doubt, `String var` is not initialised anywhere so assumes a null value by default. If it is initialised while declaring or in a constructor of the super class `App`, the value will be reflected in the instance of `Sub` as well.

Comment: Thanks Deepak for the clarification.I tried using a constructor , but did not get my expected result :(. If I give, protected  String var=""; , it will  display blank , no NULL.Is there any way to get values in subclass , sharing the variable value from super class?